# Correct way to update a python dict dynamically

Tags: python

I have a python dict containing data about a table.

```
table_dict = {'0': {'column_metadata': '...',
                    'cells':[[cell1_url],[cell2_url]]
                   },
              '1': {'column_metadata': '...',
                    'cells':[[cell1_url],[cell2_url]]
                   }
             }
```

Here keys are column position ie 0 means first column, 1 is second so on
each column has a inner dict with a key **cells** which is list of list.

I am iterating over this dict to get cell value from url and then appending it back to same list.

```
for key, column in table_dict:
    for cell in column['cells']:
        cell_value = get_cell_data(cell1_url)
        column['cells'].append(cell_value)
```

with this code I get final dict as

```
table_dict = {'0': {'column_metadata': '...',
                    'cells':[[cell1_url, cell1_data],
                             [cell2_url, cell2_data]
                            ]
                   },
              '1': {'column_metadata': '...',
                    'cells':[[cell1_url, cell1_data],
                             [cell2_url, cell2_data]
                            ]
```

I will not delete any keys just add data to dict.

Is this the correct method. Iterating over dict and then append to same.

Is there any better way to approach this problem ?

Comment: are you able to achieve what you have wished for? I do not exactly understand the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]. It's not clear what you're asking, whether what happens is the behaviour you want or not, etc.

Comment: @crazyglasses Yes I am able to achieve result but doubt I have is that Is this the correct method. Iterating over same dict and then append to some value

Comment: @pvg Please let me know what is not clear in this. I have provided the input dict and the output dict. Also the operation I am performing over it. Just want to confirm is this the correct way.

Comment: what are you doing with `table_dict` afterwards?

Comment: also, there are keys `'0'`, `'1'`, maybe use `list` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the correct way'?

Answer (score 0):

From your description I assume, you does not want to append something to `column['cells']` but to the lists inside this list:

```
for column in table_dict.values():
    for cell in column['cells']:
        cell_url = cell[0]
        cell.append(get_cell_data(cell_url))
```